# get tweet when tagged in Tweepy

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I'm working on an automatic text to speach generator using tweep and gTTS.

And what I'd like to is whenever a user tags my bot, my bot will reply with a generated TTS response of their tweet.

Example if Malcolm tweets "@bot Banana Bread" well the bot will reply to that tweet with a mp4 file of a voice saying "banana bread"

I think I could pull of the TTS generation with gTTS and some messing around.

However I don't know how I could automatically get the tweet Id and so the tweets text when I'm tagged.

The only method I see is to constantly refresh a 
`example = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='@bot').items(1)`
and then

```
for tweet in example:
    print tweet.text, tweet.id_str
```

and then store the id so that it only gets the latest posts and doesn't reply to the same tweet twice.

But this seems like a bit much, and I'm wondering if there's any faster/easier/more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Just wondering, is this the method you used in the end, and how often do you check to avoid rate limiting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is good : store tweet IDs you answered to, and check them before a new reply. With time, it can be a lot of IDs so you have to handle delete of very old ones.

Another way is to use the Twitter Account Activity API : via a webhook (an URL of your personnal web server), you can get mention events, then simply reply directly.

If i understand the official documentation, 1 free webhook is available with premium API.

Here is documentation :

- https://developer.twitter.com/en/use-cases/engage#chatbots-and-automation
- https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/subscribe-account-activity/overview